# Install custom color scheme in PhpStorm 2016.1 on Mac OSx

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

How do you install custom color schemes in PhpStorm 2016.1 on Mac OSX?

Previous versions you'd place an xml file in a directory like `~/user/webide900/colors` and PhpStorm would pick it up and make it an option for you in the settings to switch to one of those themes.

[This site](http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/) where I used to get themes appears to still be up to date but their instructions for install are for old versions.

[PhpStorm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) don't make any mention of installing custom scheme files.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To install a custom color scheme you need to create a folder named **colors** in `~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.1/`. In here you drop the `.icls` file. Hope this helps.

Comment: how about windows?

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.1/colors; mv ~/Downloads/*.icls $_`

Comment: When getting a `.xml` file like afterglow, what do I need to do to make it an `.icls` file?

Comment: Just rename it to .icls.

Comment: @GabrielAnzaldoAlvarado on Linux the color scheme directory is `~/.<PRODUCT><VERSION>/config/colors/`. Make sure files you place there have `.icls` extension (on the web, you may find `.icl` files, you will need to rename them).

Comment: Don't forget to change your `PhpStorm2016.1` to `PhpStorm2016.*` where `*` is the current version of your PHPStorm app. You can see your current version in "about PHPStorm". In my case I needed `PhpStorm2016.2`.

Answer (score 13):

**PhpStorm 2016.1 on Windows - How to install color theme**

1. Go to folder:
   `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2016.1\config\`
2. Create a new folder: **`colors`**
3. Copy the XML file of your favourite theme-color in the **`colors`** folder.
4. Open PhpStorm, go to: `File->Settings` then choose `Editor->Colors & Fonts` and your new theme-color appears in the select list.

Comment: After step 3., do not forget to restart PhpStorm because the dropdown will not be auto populated or refreshed with your installed theme. I just tried it on my PhpStorm ver. 2017.1.4. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, download a theme from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes

In PHPStorm, select File > Import Settings and select the downloaded theme file. After the IDE restarted the theme should automatically be loaded for you.

Comment: PhpStorm2016.03 says all my `.icls` files are `Invalid` when trying to import.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Ubuntu/Linux versions in 2020:

1. Find your PHPStorm folder in /home/`your user`/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm`version number`/
2. Create a new folder called `colors`.
3. Drag your .icls file in there and reload the IDE
4. Go to File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme and select your theme from the drop down box.

Example:

Mine was in /home/enigmapr0ject/.config/Jetbrains/PhpStorm2020.3, created a new folder called colors and dropped my themes in there. Worked perfectly.